# Azure Docker deployment Wait for the entrypoint process to gracefully stop the container has finished but the process is still running

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to build an App Service demo by deploying a Docker container to Azure, but I keep getting this error. I've tried restarting the app service a few times and rolling back the tag version to one I know that works, but I keept getting this error with the same timestamps, which tells me it's stuck in some infinite loop and can't restart. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[7832a410f8e185de393e723474d70881a2b71e858e78c8ac2b0300040e3f3af4] - Wait for 
the entrypoint process to gracefully stop the container has finished but the 
process is still running. Possible causes are: 1) The container doesn't handle 
the termination signals. 2) The default stop timeout is too short. The default 
timeout can be changed with the appsetting 
WEBSITES_CONTAINER_STOP_TIME_LIMIT=00:00:30. Container: 
7832a410f8e185de393e723474d70881a2b71e858e78c8ac2b0300040e3f3af4. Site: 
blingDemoSDAPI
```

Comment: Please refer [Why You Need to Wait When Stopping Your Docker Compose Services](https://vsupalov.com/docker-compose-stop-slow/) and [Gracefully Stopping Docker Containers](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)

Comment: Same issue here, any ideas? I deployed the app service with a docker image which is based on a windowservercore image. The workaround I find now is to scale up your service and then scale down to the original configuration.

Comment: @JianGuo I ended up doing the same thing, just scaling the service up and down to resolve the issue.

Comment: I changed to a Linux image to fix this issue as a workaround, my guess is windows image has an issue which is like the "pid1" issue. The container has sent a signal to our image, but our process fails to handle it.  https://betterprogramming.pub/shut-down-docker-apps-gracefully-even-when-running-in-tmux-or-screen-41e68ff17187